# Quadratic forms on the space of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space of symmetric $2 \times 2$ real matrices and

$$
q: A \in V \mapsto det(A) \in \mathbb{R}
$$

be a functional on $V$. How can I show that $q$ is a quadratic form? I have no clue.

Comment: I can´t see how the trace of a matirx can be a quadratic in something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A=\pmatrix{a & b\\b & c}$, $\det(A)=ac-b^2$ is a quadratic form in 3 variables $a,b,c$ because the (global) degree of its two terms is 2.

Said otherwise: $det(\lambda A)=\lambda^2 \det(A)$.

(homogeneous with degree 2, which is another way to characterize quadratic forms).

The bilinear form associated with this quadratic form is:

$$B((a,b,c),(a',b',c'))=\frac12(ac'+a'c)-bb'$$

Comment: Can you show that there exists a bilinear form whose quadratic form is exactly $q$?